# Apache root URL redirects to double slash

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a vhost that needs to redirect `/` to `/app` and I use following to accomplish that in vhost.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /app [R]
```

but it's giving me hard time since users get http://server.com//app address.

How to fix that?

Comment: I don't get double slashes when I put those rules in a blank vhost.

Comment: Your rules seem OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/local$ grep Redirect /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
        RedirectMatch ^/$ /app

suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/local$ curl http://127.0.0.1/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://127.0.0.1/app">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Ok I found my problem.
After redirecting, the application itself redirects the page to /login.

So to avoid double redirect I simply redirect the root to correct page at the first place.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/login.axvw [R]

Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like after redirecting, the application itself redirects the page to `/login`.

So to avoid double redirect simply redirect the root `/` to the correct page and add this to the apache config in your `/etc/apache/sites-available/vhost.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/login.axvw [R]
```